# Is using "PBUH" as respectable as saying/writing "Peace Be Upon Him"?

Tags: honorifics, salawat

<sup>(I know very little about Islam so please keep your answers understandable to those that don't know all the terms.)</sup>

I understand that *"PBUH"* is an abbreviation for *"Peace Be Upon Him"*, which is an honorific to show love and respect to the mentioned persons.

Is this as honorable as fully saying the statement 'Peace Be Upon Him'?

Are there examples of PBUH being used *before* the internet was here, because it seems like a bit of a shortcut, which to me seems a bit less respectable.

As an example, it would be like a man telling his wife "I love you Susie" from his own heart. Then one day the man wrote the letters "ILYS" on his hand and every time he mentioned his wife's name he'd show her his hand.

Does the Quran state that this kind of abbreviation is equally honoring and respectable?

Comment: PBUH is what used in writing, but when saying it is "Peace be upon him"

Answer (score 3):

The abbreviation "PBUH" is used in writing to make an abbreviation to the sentence "Peace Be Upon Him" because it seems to long for writing especially in a live conversation, but mainly it is used to remind you to pray for the prophet Muhammad "**PBUH**"

> as you can notice i've tipped PBUH but when you read it in the flow of the text you say in your mind Peace Be Upon Him

thats why we use PBUH in tipping conversations but in oral conversations we use the  " Peace be Upon Him " statue.

+1 if it helped, thank you.